# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, 17.10

After upgrading from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10, I get a warning about that option `-e` is deprecated when starting `gnome-terminal` from the command line. For example, assume I want to open a gnome-terminal with two tabs, and running separate commands in each tab:

```
$ gnome-terminal --tab --active -e 'bash -c "echo Hello; exec bash"' --tab -e 'bash -c "echo Hello2; exec bash"'
Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
```

But how can I run separate commands for each tab if I am supposed to use `--` to terminate the options? For example, the following does not work:

```
$ gnome-terminal --tab --active -- bash -c "echo Hello; exec bash" --tab -- bash -c "echo Hello2; exec bash"
```

It just opens a single tab.

Comment: You should report bug on `gnome-terminal` package to [bugs.launchpad.net](http://bugs.launchpad.net) with `ubuntu-bug` and/or upstream. This functionality works in `mate-terminal`.

Comment: @Norbert Added report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1726380

Comment: Upstream bug report: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=784925

Comment: I merged bugs on [bug 1726380 at launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-terminal/+bug/1726380), thanks!

Comment: but does `gnome-terminal --tab --active -- bash -c "echo Hello; exec bash"` + `gnome-terminal --tab --active -- bash -c "echo Hello2; exec bash"` do what you want?

Comment: Looking at the man page, the command is formatted as a string. Have you tried enclosing the whole command in quotes before specifying the rest?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following command would do the trick for you:

```
gnome-terminal --tab --active -- bash -c "echo Hello; exec bash" && gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -c "echo Hello2; exec bash"
```